# Authentication for React Native in AWS Amplify in November 2022 to beyond

Tags: react-native, authentication, aws-amplify

I've been struggling setting up authentication using withAuthenticator as the old documentation suggested on AWS Amplify. The old one was not working, and the next one wasn't released yet. So, if like me you used to use withAuthenticator to wrap your RN app, now you can find the new way to do it here :

https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/react-native/connected-components/authenticator

I'm posting it here because it has not always been easy to find this doc, especially a few weeks ago they were almost no link pointing to it when you searched about react native as it wasn't ready  yet.

If you'r beginning on Amplify x React Native like me, you'll find useful to know that to get the current user, provided you are insided an `Authenticator.Provider` component, you can do

```js
import { useAuthenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react-native';
const { user, signOut } = useAuthenticator((context) => [context.user]);
```

With that you will access the sub_id of your Cognito User.

Before mid November 2022, I had to use `withAuthenticator` to wrap my app and it doesn't work anymore as it seems like the libraries you have to import to setup Authentication on an RN Amplify project have changed.

Comment: If you feel like this provides value and should be a self-answer you need to actually split it into question and answer.

Comment: Really relevant, indeed. Unfortunately the React Native Authenticator is currently in developer preview. But I am using `withAuthenticator` HOC and it is working fine. In addition, it is possible to build custom authentication flows with the [Amplify Library for JS](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/getting-started/q/platform/react-native/).